# explicit instantiation of template function imported from std in own namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, clang, std

I'm trying to hook an existing namespace onto **std** functionality by "using" some specific std math functions. The problem is that for coverage reasons i'd like to **explicitly instantiate the template functions** before i actually use them anywhere. Afterwards i want to write some unit tests that verify the functionality.

Example

```
namespace foo {
    using std::sin;
    // ...
}
```

This works fine, such that i can write

```
foo::sin(0);
```

but, the explicit template instantiation doesn't work

```
template double foo::sin<int>(int); // doesn't work (this is what i want)
```

If i instantiate std::sin directly, it works.

```
template double std::sin<int>(int); // works
```

Can this this kind of **reusing of namespace functionality** be achieved for explicit template instantiations?

**Edit**

Someone marked this question as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912440/specialisation-of-function-template-in-another-class-namespace), but this post seems to have a different problem. I do **NOT** want to define a specialization of a function template (std namespace to my own that is). Rather, i want my namespace to "imitate" the std namespace for some math functions.

**Edit 2**

I'm using clang 9 which throws an error. GCC happily compiles the code. (see comments below)

Comment: What happens when you use `template double foo::sin<int>(int);`? Does it fail to compile? Does it fail to actually generate the specialization?

Comment: error: explicit instantiation of 'sin' does not refer to a function template, variable template, member function, member class, or static data member
template double foo::sin<int>(int);

Comment: It seems like [it works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/6Pq5eG). How are you compiling your code? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Interesting. GCC compiles. I'm using clang 9.0.0 and get the error i mentioned above. A lot of posts online about namespaces and gcc vs. clang. For me it's still not clear how i can achieve what i want though..